# How to load a view's ajax when the view is programmatically loaded

Tags: views

I am embedding a (calendar) view withing another view by using the following code (in a theme)..

```
        <div class="calendar-calendar">
          <?php echo views_embed_view('event_calendar', 'year_plan'); ?>
        </div>
```

The calendar itself is loading perfectly, however, it does have "Prev" and "Next" year links, which increment the year.  When you click on them, they navigate to a new page, with JUST this calendar view displayed.

I'd like them to navigate the years using the ajax it uses when I load the view without embedding.   Is it possible to load the ajax associated with these navigation links programmatically?

Comment: Note that [documentation of `views_embed_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) says: "this provides a worthwhile guide to doing so".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable ajax in the views. Probably you have to do it in both parent and child view.

To do so : go to `Advanced -> Use Ajax`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, however Ajax is turned on, and works when I load the view independently.  However, when embed the view in another, it doesn't work.

Comment: My apologies, I just checked and the parent ajax was turned off, you were right!  Thank you very much!